# Map book based on field attributes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cartography, mxd, data-driven-pages, map-book

I have a polygon shapefile with 800 records. What I want to do is to create an MXD document and a map in jpg for every polygon record from the shp.

Is this posible to be done with data driven pages or map book in ArcGis or by using any other tool?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? if so, what did you do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you need 800 separate MXDs? You can make a map for each of the 800 polygons in a single MXD using data driven pages (DDP) simply by setting the layer with 800 polygons as your index layer. Then, DDP will iterate over each feature in that layer and export a map in whatever format you want. Check out the help file here: http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//00s90000003n000000.

Using 800 different MXDs won't work with DDP. You'd have to write some code of your own that iterates through each MXD and exports a map.

Comment: For sure, 800 different MXDs would not be ideal, unless you had some specific reason for that.  The question relates because DDP is based on polygons that will have some specific attribute. If you are looking for a way that someone could easily get to a map area, you could write a Python Add-In with a combo box/drop down with the attributes and zoom to selection.

Comment: +1 Data driven pages is definitely the way to go here.  It will give you exactly what you are looking for without the complication of having 800 MXD files.  The help page that is linked is very good.  ESRI also has a free seminar here: http://training.esri.com/gateway/index.cfm?fa=catalog.webCourseDetail&courseID=2152.

Comment: I know that is useless to create 800 MXDs but unfortunately my client requested that.